# Firebase returning null for Data values in Android

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

All data.getValue() are returning null. I can get child key to return fine. I can write to firbase fine. Just data.getValue is returning null for some unknown reason. I have other classes working fine using the exact same format.

```
//method for retrieving info from firebase which has notifications
private void retrieveInfo(){
    Firebase ref = new Firebase("https://fitnectapp.firebaseio.com/");

    // Attach an listener to read the data at our posts reference
    ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        // Retrieve new posts as they are added to the database
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
            getUpdates(snapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            getUpdates(snapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
            getUpdates(snapshot);
        }
        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot snapshot, String previousChildKey) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
        }
    });
}

//All data values returning null??
private void getUpdates(DataSnapshot ds) {
    if (ds.getKey().equals("notifications")) {
        for (DataSnapshot data : ds.getChildren()) {
            String user = sp.getString("username", null);
            Notification notification = data.getValue(Notification.class);
            if(notification.getNotifUser().equals(user)){
                String sender = notification.getNotifSender();
                String workout = notification.getNotifWorkout();
                String notificationTxt = sender + " has liked your workout, " + workout;
                notifications.add(notificationTxt);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not enough info, it might be an Object mapping problem so you might wanna add the "Notification" class code, as well as the JSON tree for your firebase DB

Comment: I would consider putting logs in your code in various places to make sure that the conditions you are setting up are being satisfied, and to check that you are getting the values you expect AT EVERY STEP along the way... then you can see where the problem is.

Comment: I did the Logs and would get all values except the one needed. I was able to get it to work using another class called UserInfo I had. For some reason the Notification class kept returning null with the exact same setup as the other UserInfo class.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with data.getValue(); function, although i did logged and debugged data and it returns a strange string showing on the screen by the debugger and still the object is null, have you found any solution? or reason for the issue?